# What is better way to randomize HMAC calculation?

Tags: cryptography, hmac

I need to calculate HMAC when sending some data1. HMAC key is shared between sender-recipient. Sender-recipient also share some data2 (which changes frequently on runtime) which I could use to randomize HMAC calculation. What would be better and why?:

1. create new key using shared key and data2
2. use shared key over data1+data2 concatenation

Comment: Use [HKDF](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/76588/18298) to generate new keys per `data2`and generate new keys with ECDH according to your key schedule...

Comment: Neither option is bad. However, there are a lot of unknowns; you say that data2 changes *frequently*, but if that frequency is too on the receivers side then you might have to deal with replay attacks. We also don't know how many times the shared key is changed. If it is used indefinitely or over large volumes of data, it might be a good idea to derive a new key.